# How can I access the 8080 port to go to the Tomcat website?

Tags: tomcat, centos7

I have installed apach-tomcat(7.0) in my Linux system (CentOs 4 64) and started it, but I cannot get access to it in my local browser.

The command:
'firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp'

gives the message that:

Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 8080/tcp
success.

However, the command 'netstat | grep 8080' 
still gives me nothing. (I have used the 'firewall-cmd --reload').

I cannot get access to tomcat via 'http://localhost:8080', my network is of mode 'NAT' with ip addr dynamically allocated. I have restarted my system, but it doesn't work, could anybody help me with this? Is my 8080 port opened or not?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command "firewall-cmd --list-ports", it says the firewall status is "dead". So I used "systemctl start firewalld" to activate it. Then "firewall-cmd --list-ports" shows "8080/tcp" and finally I can access the tomcat online.

I don't know exactly where I was wrong, but since those are the only changes I have made since the failure, I think that should be related to the firewall status.